# Method to know if rendering finished on JOGL Canvas

Tags: opengl, jogl

Is there a method in JOGL library which tells if the GLCanvas rendering has finished?? 
Or is there a method which is called when rendering is finished.

Comment: You could block until rendering has finished with `glFinish()` or use [sync](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Object) objects.

Comment: Why not simply using a GLEventListener to do it?